# Kill empty process id

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile, I have the following to kill all my running nginx processes:

```
killNginx:
  sudo kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep [n]ginx | awk '{print $2}')
```

The problem is that it gives me an error when there are no nginx processes running.  Is there a way I can run the kill command only if nginx is running?

EDIT:

Actually I think the issue is the $2 not getting executed.  I tried $$2 but still does not work. Anyone have any other ideas to escape $2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way that made it work for me:

```
killNginx:
  ps -ef | grep [n]ginx | awk '{print $$2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape every single `$` in your recipe that does not introduce a make variable.  So, you need to escape both `$$(ps ...` *and* `print $$2`.  You seem to be implying that this isn't your problem: however there's no way this will even come close to working without that.

You can also look into killall.  Something like `killall -I nginx || true` might do it.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
for PID in $(ps -ef | grep [n]ginx | awk '{ print $2 }'); do
    sudo kill -9 $PID
done
```